# Sign SOAP request in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have client spring boot application that communicate with SOAP server. I need to sign the SOAP request. All tutorials is referencing xml configs. Is thiere any easy way to configure in via spring boot?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the related [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html)

Comment: This what I mean by xml configs. I'm looking for java-config \ annotation-config way to do it

Comment: Let me tell you a secret, those xml tags, include classnames... Those classname you can use to instantiate new beans... The `property` elements `name` attribute is nothing more then a setter which you can call... Now with that knowledge it shouldn't be that hard to translate xml into java config.